# Telling rspec to not add directories to $LOAD_PATH

Tags: ruby, rspec

Rspec is automatically adding the lib directory for my project to the load_path. Is there any way to tell it not to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As far as I know, no one's ever wanted it to not do this before.

What problems is it causing for you?  Most users find it very convenient that rspec adds `lib` to the load path.

You can always remove the directory from the load path if you don't want it there.

Comment: It's causing the wrong file to be loaded when I do a `require`. Thanks for responding, I'll just take it out of the path.